# ODBC Conncetion to MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, odbc, linked-tables

I have a database built by a commercial company.  Their reporting is basically non-existent.  They have a few canned reports but not what we need.  Of course, they highly recommend not connecting to the database and can build custom reports for a "small fee".

My thoughts were to connect to the database using linked tables, then use something like Business Objects, Access, or even Excel to build all the reports I want for a "small fee".  The only means I know to do this requires an ODBC connection.  I have downloaded / installed the MySQL 5.1 Driver.  But, I am having issues connecting.

I have a user name and password for the server.  When I try the test connection I get

> Connection Failed: [HY000][MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Access denied for
>   the user 'userrname'@ '....'(using password: YES).

Tried establishing a read only account as well without a password and received the same error message but at the end it says

> (using password: NO)

Any suggestions as to what is causing this?  Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Things you need to do:

1. Make sure you have the user/password correct.
2. Make sure you are granted access to the database with: `grant all privileges on db.* to 'youruser'@'your ip' identified by 'YOURPASSWORD'`;